# Shell not expanding *

Tags: linux, bash, shell, java

I am setting up a java classpath in a bash script. I thought that I would have to use quotes to prevent shell from expanding the `*` based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath,
but the following works just fine without quotes:

```
classpath=/jars/*:/anotherJarsDir/*
java -classpath=$classpath com.test.MyClass
```

However, shell will expand this:

```
classpath=/jars/*
java -classpath=$classpath com.test.MyClass
```

It appears I do not have to worry about shell expansion messing up my java classpath if there are multiple directories in the classpath variable?

Answer (score 1):

`classpath=` is shell syntax for assigning a variable, so the shell knows that the thing after may be a path to expand. that means, we have to look at `/jars/*` and `/jars/*:/anotherJarsDir/*`. the first one has a directory prefix and a wildcard, the second one is interpreted as "any file in a directory named `anotherJarsDir`, in a directory ending in a colon (this is the `*:`), in the `/jars` directory.

Note that the shell is not aware that the colon is a path separator; it interprets it as part of the directory name. If you had a file `/jars/wx:/anotherJarsDir/yz`, then your path would match that, but multiple files would be separated by spaces, not by colons, and java would in turn interpret that as a `/jars/wx` file and a `/anotherJarsDir/yz` file (assuming this is the only file, thus not resulting in spaces in your classpath)

Conclusion: if you want to avoid expansion, quote your strings, even if an unquoted string works in corner cases!

Answer (score 0):

The shell will only expand wildcards if there are matches. If no files match the pattern, the wildcard will be preserved. However, Java and the shell disagrees about what the `:` character  actually means. In the classpath environment variable, it's used as a separator between different items. The shell on the other hand considers it a valid directory character like any other. The only reason the first example doesn't expand is because `/jars/*:/anotherJarsDir/*` happens to not match any directories. If, against all odds, you would have a directory called something like `/jars/123:/anotherJarsDir/456`, the wildcards would be expanded to reflect this. In other words, do always quote your `classpath` definition.